# Placeholders in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, autolisp

Are people able to set placeholders in batch files and then reference that data in other scripts?

For example if I have a batch file which I set the Project number in.

```
%Project Number%

set Project Number=AA00XXXX
```

And I then want to use that placeholder that was prompted for in an Autocad Lisp routine or script.

I'm assuming that you could reference the file location, so F:\blah\blah\blah test.bat just not sure if it is physically possible to therefore go into the batch and grab a figure.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` puts the variable into the environment. Only the program that does it (`set` is part of `CMD`) and programs started in that console get a copy of their parent's program's environment. If autocad was started after set was issued and from the same console it can access it's environmental variables. See `set /?`.

`Setx` does the system, but only explorer notices changes, so only new programs started by explorer will have the changes. See `setx /?`.

Use the `call` statement to treat a another batch as a function. See `call /?`.

Comment: hmm i might have got a bit confused, not sure the environment portion is really what i was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible through a .BAT file. AutoCAD will understand what's in the .SCR (Script) file that you pass during startup

acad.exe /s "c:\folder\script.scr"

You may edit this script before launch AutoCAD...

Or use AutoCAD COM API to automate tasks, but that's a complete different approach.